# PnP-js-core Document form

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, form, pnp, pnp-js-core

Is there any example or guide to start using PnP-JS-core in the forms?
Sharepoint Online.

I've been looking for a while without luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the PnP Core starting point

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki

This library makes calling REST endpoints easier,

so if you don't have experience in JavaScript or using REST,
then those technologies are your starting point.

Comment: Thank you Danny, however that documentation is not finished. Basic operations was wmpty yesterday, today they have published something. So I was hoping to get more information

Comment: That's the official documentation. Best thing is to  watch the videos Patrick and Vesa put out every two weeks. https://dev.office.com/blogs/introducing-pnp-javascript-special-interest-group

Answer (score 0):

You can find here all the documentation of Office Dev PnP: https://dev.office.com/blogs/PnP-November-2016-Release

And here you can follow interested tutorials videos: http://aka.ms/sppnp-videos